# Using the sendgrid API in PHP

Tags: email, sendgrid

I'm looking to use the parse api on sendgrid and am having trouble setting it up. i establish my email.php file:

ok

From here i'd like to put my post variables into a database but i don't seem to have access to the post variables. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: If SendGrid is posting to your script properly, they should exist within $_POST or $_REQUEST. Can you try printing out the headers when a request comes in to see that the body of the request contains all of the fields you're expecting?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest creating a ticket here: http://support.sendgrid.com/ or ask for advice in live chat.